# How do I enter fullscreen mode with a specified resolution using GLUT?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

While glutFullScreen() make the window full-screen, it doesn't change the screen resolution. It is actually equivalent to resize the window to the screen's size and hide the title bar and the border.

How do I change the resolution to a specified one?

I'm using Ubuntu/Mesa/FreeGlut/C.

Answer (score 2):

You can try calling [glutGameModeString()](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__gamemode.html#ga0) followed by [glutEnterGameMode()](http://openglut.sourceforge.net/group__gamemode.html#ga1). Depending on your system, it might be able to change the screen resolution:

```
glutGameModeString("800x600:32@60");
glutEnterGameMode();
```

Comment: No, it failed. Actually, It indeed changed the size of the window to 800x600 and hide its title bar and border, but it simply fixed the window on the left-top corner of my screen, limited my mouse in this window area and blocked all the keyboard input. I think something prevent it from changing the resolution.

Comment: @trVoldemort, it's not always possible to change the resolution of an X server on the fly (IIRC, the XRandR extension is required and the video driver must support it). What happens if you run the `xrandr` command from a terminal?